# Converting rows to columns based on a row condition

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to merge the rows x1..x3 in a single column based on the unique identification of postal code.

Current table:

| postalcode | x1 | x2 | x3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| T2Z4Y6 | -113.97203 | -113.972029 | -113.972027 |
| T2Z0H4 | -113.972411 | -113.972783 | -113.97294 |

And, I want to transpose the same in rows as below:

| postalcode | x |
| --- | --- |
| T2Z4Y6 | -113.97203 |
| T2Z4Y6 | -113.972029 |
| T2Z4Y6 | -113.972027 |
| T2Z0H4 | -113.972411 |
| T2Z0H4 | -113.972783 |
| T2Z0H4 | -113.97294 |

How can I do the same in SQL?

Comment: The tag SQL-Server is for the product by Microsoft. If you're using BigQuery, tag it as that. They have different syntax, behaviour, etc, as you can see from the answer you commented on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UNION ALL`. For example:

```
select postalcode, x1 as x
union all select postalcode, x2
union all select postalcode, x3
...
union all select postalcode, x10
```